# How can I have all my SFTP users created files be in a certain group?

Tags: apache-2.2, user-permissions

The problem is, they're all creating files for the website and I always have to change the group to `www-data` so they have permission to it. I can run a cron job, but that seems like a ghetto fix. The users are creating a file locally and just transferring it via SFTP through programs such as Transmit. I am sure I am not the only one having this problem, so I wanted to know how others handled it.

This is the setup I used:
http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/setgid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the group of the directory to the group you want and then set the [sgid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) permission bit. That should do the trick.

```
$ chgrp ftpusers /data/ftp
$ chmod g+s $_
```

Comment: What is `$_`? Also, I thought this was a pretty good explanation of sgid: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/

Comment: Oh wow! Interesting, it is the first argument of the last command. That is really new to me!

Comment: The $_ is also new to me, but this is the *LAST* argument of the previous command

Comment: Sorry, probably seems cryptic for people unfamiliar to the syntax. Should have used the folder name instead. But I suppose I underhandedly introduced something to some people ;-)